# Gremlin order on Map results

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, amazon-neptune

I have the below query:

```
g.V('1')
    .union(
        out('R1')
            .project('timestamp', 'data')
                .by('completionDate')
                .by(valueMap().by(unfold()))
        out('R2')
            .project('timestamp', 'data')
                .by('endDate')
                .by(valueMap().by(unfold()))
        )
```

How can I order the UNION results by timestamp?
I've tried using ".order().by('timestamp')" but this only works on traversals and UNION returns a MAP object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to approach it. First, you could just use your code as-is and then `order()` by the "timestamp":

```
g.V('1').
  union(out('R1').
          project('timestamp', 'data').
            by('completionDate').
            by(valueMap().by(unfold())),
        out('R2').
          project('timestamp', 'data').
            by('endDate').
            by(valueMap().by(unfold()))).
  order().by(select('timestamp'))
```

Note the difference is to `select()` the key from the `Map` that you want to sort on. Versions after 3.4.5 will work [more as you expect](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.5/upgrade/#_by_string_modulator) and you can simply do `by('timestamp')` for a `Map` as well as an `Element`.

I think that a more readable approach however would be to go with this approach:

```
g.V('1').
  out('R1','R2').
  project('timestamp', 'data').
    by(coalesce(values('endDate'), values('completionDate'))).
    by(valueMap().by(unfold())).
  order().by(select('timestamp'))
```

You might need to enhance the `by(coalesce(...))` depending on the nature of your schema, but hopefully you get the idea of what I'm trying to do there.

Comment: The 1st approach worked perfectly. Thank you. I'm not entirely sure about the 2nd approach. There is no property called 'timestamp' on R1 or R2. So I don't really understand how the order by timestamp would work in this case. I will test and come back with another comment.

Comment: sorry - i revised the second query.